# Cross-browser Grid layout

Tags: css, sass, cross-browser

When I start to check my grid layout on Edge there is some kind of problem with the display. Chrome accepts my `grid-template-columns: n n n n` without problems, where `n` is my columns.

[image]

But Edge needs `-ms-` prefix and `-ms-grid-columns` is not working for me.

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}

.grid div {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #CCF;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE\Edge uses old syntax and works according to [old version of grid specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-grid-layout-20110407/). The issue is that IE\Edge don't have auto-placement functionality, so unless you manually specify `-ms-grid-column` and `-ms-grid-row` for every grid item, they will stack in very first cell as you can see in your screenshot

[image]

So to fix this, I'll specify row and column for every grid item. I've omitted `-ms-grid-row: 1` and `-ms-grid-column: 1` because it's default values. Demo:

```css
.grid {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 200px 200px 200px;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px;
  -ms-grid-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}

.grid div {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #CCF;
}

.grid > :nth-child(2) {
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
}

.grid > :nth-child(3) {
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
}

.grid > :nth-child(4) {
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
}

.grid > :nth-child(5) {
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
}

.grid > :nth-child(6) {
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
}

.grid > :nth-child(7) {
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
</div>
```